# Changing the Magento category URLs

Tags: magento

I am working in Magento EE 1.10.1.1,

I changed the categories URLs from admin panel, but in frond-end(menu) still the old are showing. I run re-index and clear all caches.

Can anybody know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my bad, the re-index takes much time to complete. It starts works once re-index completes.